# Need to change usbport access to all users

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

I need to have full access to USB port to read and write from it, it's for a script I'm developing, I know what the security risks are, I just need to know how could I change those permissions in order to read the values of the USB peripheral from my script.

How can I change the permissions on those items?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Also I can't find where the peripheral is mounted (I come from a Linux background and things are slightly different there).